# How to remove style attribute from object in GAS

Tags: styles, google-apps-script

Is there any way how to remove style attribute from some html element?

For example I created text-box and I'm checking its value in my onSubmit(). If it have wrong value I change its background color to red. If I change its value to white after user submits correct value, it does not look same as unchanged text-boxes.

I tried function `setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor", "")` but it throws an error, `setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor", "none")` but it did not change anything.

Comment: This question is about removing style from object. Replacing style value with some other is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might try "transparent" or "inherit"

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp

Comment: oooops sorry Michael didn't see your answer while writing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.setStyleAttribute('background','transparent')` it should result in the same state as initial state... hmmm well I think ;-)

---

**EDIT :** (following your comment)

When you create a widget without any style it doesn't mean it has no style, it only means that you are using the 'default' style. So I guess setting a value to the default value might well be the right thing to do.

In the example of the background color the default is "transparent" and the result applied to the textBox is what you expected, isn't it ?